# reCaptcha by BestWebSoft" v.3

Tags: recaptcha

Yesterday afternoon we installed and activated the spam protection of the contact form in WP via "reCaptcha by BestWebSoft" v.3. Early this morning, we and our internet provider were surprised that several spams came through the contact form. Can you please check why the spam protection is not working?

I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.